# React.JS Strange Bug: Button Moving with Scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

I am creating a react.js hackathon project due in less than 12 hours. I am trying to create a medical planner for hospitals. Unfortunately, the buttons of my forms are moving and following the user's scrolling up and down. [image: buttons at the bottom][image: buttons moving up]
Here is my code:

```
      <StickyFooter
      bottomThreshold={50}
      normalStyles={{
      backgroundColor: "#50E3C2",
      padding: "1rem"
      }}
      stickyStyles={{
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.8)",
      padding: "2rem"
      }}>
    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmitBack}>
     <Button outline className="backButton" size="lg">Back</Button>
    </Form>
    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
     <Button outline className="proceedButton" 
     size="lg">Proceed</Button>
    </Form>
    </StickyFooter>
```

Comment: sounds more like a css problem

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue because I have not coded css for the button yet

Comment: Those Components you use, are they your own or from some library? If the latter, try contacting the devs through their github? Or see if there is already an issue about it. Also, try inspecting the "ghosting" elements and the original to get some insight of what's going on.

Comment: It is from a react.js library. I think I figured out the problem: I am using StickyFooter which means that all the components of the footer follow the user's scrolling. I am wondering whether there is some other type of footer available for that?

Comment: @nikpap pap you can make the footer yourself in less than 5 minutes

Comment: @nikpap not sure what `StickyFooter` does but sounds right based on the name.

Comment: the problem is that I need the footer to look like how it looks in the first picture